# Dividing array in two different array in ios

Tags: ios, arrays

Hi i am using an array  in my program there are some string present like
    "Portland, OR",
    "Cincinnati, OH",
    "Los Angeles, CA",
    "Charlotte, NC",
    "Seattle, WA",
    "St. Paul, MN",
    "Buffalo, NY",
    "Nashville, TN",
    "Pittsburgh, PA",
    "Berkeley, CA",
    "San Francisco, CA",

i want to store the string like OH,CA,NC,WA,MN,NY,TN,PA,CA,CA in another array how can i do it, 
please tell me?
if i do it this way

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i<[cityArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString * string = [cityArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString  *firstName = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","][0];
    [_NewCityArray addObject:firstName];
}
```

i get only values in newcityarray as 
    Portland,
    Cincinnati,
    "Los Angeles",
    Charlotte,
    Seattle,
    "St. Paul",
    Buffalo,
    Nashville,
    Pittsburgh,
    Berkeley,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<[cityArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString * string = [cityArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if ([array count] == 2) {
        [_NewCityArray addObject:array[0]];
        [_OtherArray addObject:array[1]];
    }
}
```

OH,CA... is stored in `_OtherArray`.